# Trying to make a bug log in a ruby program. How can I write to a file without over-writing the data?

Tags: ruby

Trying to make a bug log into a Ruby program so that when I come across bugs I can run the program and it will automatically write the bugs to a text file. I was able to get everything to write to a file but every time that I enter a new bug in it just overwrites the file and only can hold one entry at a time.

Here is my code thus far:

```
print "What is the error message? "
msg = "Error message: " + gets.chomp
print "What does the error mean? "
mean = "Error meaning: "+gets.comp
print "What resolved the error? "
resolved = "Error resolution: " + gets.comp
File.open('Bug_Log.txt', 'w') do |write|
        write.puts msg
        write.puts mean
        write.puts resolved
end
```

Answer (score 7):

This is happening because you're opening the file in 'w' mode, which overwrites the file, instead of 'a' ("append") mode, which will append to what's already in the file.

Try changing this line:

```
File.open('Bug_Log.txt', 'w') do |write|
```

to this:

```
File.open('Bug_Log.txt', 'a') do |write|
```